# AngularJS: ng-repeat and ng-class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I've a problem with ng-repeat and ng-class. I want to apply class only if the param "sel" is true. My data is about this:
`people = [{"id":0,"name":"Simone","sel":true},{"id":1,"name":"Maria","sel":false},{"id":2,"name":"Marco","sel":false}]`

In my html page I've:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people" id="person-{{person.id}}">
        <span ng-class="{person-select: person.sel == 'true'}">{{person.name}}</span>
</li>
```

But it doesn't work.. Where I'm wrong? I tried with `{{person.name}}-{{person.sel}}` and it print "Simone-true .. Maria-false .. Marco-false".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that you are comparing a `boolean` value with a `string`.

```
true == 'true' // will return false
```

The second problem is that the name of the class is not wrapped in `'`.

Bellow code fixes both issues:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people" id="person-{{person.id}}">
    <span ng-class="{'person-select': person.sel}">{{person.name}}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Yes, works. For first problem, I know, but I do a lot of attemps. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 2):

wrap the class name with ' .

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people" id="person-{{person.id}}">
        <span ng-class="{'person-select': person.sel == 'true'}">{{person.name}}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but adding on to this. 
I had to apply CSS from person (from the list) and also needed to add a class conditionally. 
Here is the syntax for that.

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people" id="person-{{person.id}}">
    <span ng-class="[person.someClass, {'person-select': person.sel}]">{{person.name}}</span>
</li>
```

Here `person.someClass` is a class from the list and `'person-select'` is a conditional class.